# flutter push notification wake up terminated app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a delivery app (similar to uber eats) with flutter. I want the restaurant owner to get notified whenever a new order arrives.

Basically what I need is either a non-stopping sound to be played e.g. along with the notification in the notification tray, or even better popup that displays some message. That needs to be achieved even when the phone is inactive, and even when the app is not running in the background.

However with the FCM Plugin it seems impossible to achieve this "waking up" of the app. Can anyone suggest any workaround?

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. Did you find a way of doing it?